# How do I provide an existing provider from `main` to `app`

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

In Flutter I currently have the following basic app structure (simplified):

```dart
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String get value => 'Hello!';
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: MyProvider()),
      ],
      builder: (context, _) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(context.read<MyProvider>().value),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, `MyProvider` needs an async `init` method. I thought I could initialize the provider in the main function and then pass it along to the app and eventually to the MultiProvider, like so:

```dart
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<void> init() async {
    // Something async
  }

  String get value => 'Hello!';
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final myProvider = MyProvider();
  await myProvider.init();

  final app = MyApp(
    providers: [
      myProvider,
    ],
  );
  runApp(app);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key, this.providers = const []});

  final List<ChangeNotifier> providers;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ...providers.map((p) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: p)),
      ],
      builder: (context, _) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(context.read<MyProvider>().value),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as it throws a `ProviderNotFoundException`.
I'm struggling to see why though. To me, the two versions seem almost identical, as the actual `ChangeNotifierProvider` is created in the same place. Only the value is created somewhere else.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

As a side note, I know I could make my app work by wrapping the `MaterialApp` inside a `FutureBuilder` and initializing the provider there, but that just looks ugly and suboptimal.

Comment: Could you include the code where the `this.providers` is defined?

Answer (score 1):

Update your provider like this:

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  MyProvider() {
    init();
  }
  Future<void> init() async {
    // Something async
  }
  String get value => 'Hello!';
}
```

When you initialize the provider, the `init` function is automatically called.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
          create: (context) => MyProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      builder: (context, _) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text(context.read<MyProvider>().value),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap MyApp widget into MultiProvider

```
main() async {
  final p = MyProvider();
  await p.init();

  runApp(
   MultiBlocProvider(
     providers:[
       ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>.value(value: p),
     ],
     child: MyApp()
   )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the `ChangeNotifierProvider`'s passed to the `MultiProvider` you are not indicating the *type* of those notifiers (the type of the provided model), consequently it cannot be found in the BuildContext the provider which has that type `MyProvider`.

You shall declarte as `Provider<YourModel>` instead of just `Provider`. Where **YourModel** in your case is **MyProvider**.

NOTE: You are using the suffix "Provider" but it is actually a ChangeNotifier.

You shall define the type of provider and then pass the actual `Provider` (not the `ChangeNotifier`) as an argument to your `MyApp`:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final notifier = MyChangeNotifier();
  await notifier.init();
  final provider = ChangeNotifierProvider<MyChangeNotifier>.value(value: notifier);
  
  runApp(MyApp(
    providers: [provider],
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key, this.providers = const []});

  final List<SingleChildWidget> providers;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: providers,
  ...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks! While your solution is totally reasonable, it has now brought me down a rabbithole of questions about OOP :).